# Assigning a function while subsetting a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Is there a specific reason why one cannot perform the following action?

```
v <- data.table( A = 1:2, B = vector("list", 2) )
#    A B
# 1: 1  
# 2: 2  

v[ A == 1, B := list( identity ) ]
# RHS of assignment is not NULL, not an an atomic vector (see ?is.atomic) and not a list column.
```

Note that `B` *is* a list column. On the other hand the following is possible (though giving a warning):

```
v[ A == 1, B := list(2) ]
```

Comment: `identity` is a function

Comment: upgrade your data.table and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap the function in a `list` as it is a function

```
v[A == 1,  B := list(list(identity))]
v
#   A          B
#1: 1 <function>
#2: 2
```

Comment: Excellent, I would have expected that `list(identity)` was added to the column `B`.

Answer (score 1):

When assigning to list columns, the rule of thumb in `data.table` is "you always need one `list()` more than you would expect"

```
v[ A == 1, B := list(list(identity)) ]
```

does what you want. Your example with the integer value worked because in this case `data.table` automatically coerces `2` to `list(2)` (but with a warning as you stated).

Comment: I see, though this is not quite consistent with e.g. the syntax `v <- data.table( A = 1:2, B = list( identity, c) ) `

Comment: @FOMH consistency is now improved in recent version